# PHP: How to replace word A with word B in a string - A and B being in an array [] and [+1]

Tags: php, replace

I'm a beginner.

I want to read a CSV, and if a string contains some word - which would be (position)[x] in the array from the CSV - I want to replace it with word B (position[x+1]).

I have read a lot of posts which may contain the answer, but I could not get it to work.
Here´s what I have so far:

```
$handle = fopen('xyz.csv')
$csv    = fgetcsv($handle);
$input  = "The fox ate the chicken";
$blub   = str_replace($csv[find_value], $csv[find_value + 1]$input);
```

Comment: You should provide some sample input data and the corresponding desired result.

Comment: And just the first line in the CSV or what?

Comment: e.g. the csv could be (fox, cow, ate, manured, chicken, grass)</br>...the input "The fox ate the chicken</br>...the desired output "The cow manured the grass".</br>The words-to-find and the words-to-replace-with occur always in pairs, always the find, and then the replacement.

Comment: no, every line of the csv. Each line in the csv consists of a pair of words: the one to look for, and the one to replace with

Comment: `str_replace()` accepts arrays as the search and replace arguments.  So loop through the CSV array and for each line, add the first element to a `$search` array and the second to a `$replace` array.  Then pass those to `str_replace()`.

Comment: you can also use preg_replace with the pattern to replace a substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$handle = fopen('xyz.csv', 'r');     // don't forget the mode
$replace = [];
// read file line by line and fill `$replace` array
while (($csv = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
    $replace[$csv[0]] = $csv[1];
}
$inputs  = "The fox ate the chicken";
// perform replacement
$blub = strtr($inputs, $replace);
```

[`strtr` manual.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

Comment: I apologize for the delay! I´m inexperienced.